# the spring boot oauth2 doc teaches deprecated annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

it's a confusing problem but suffered me several days.

Firstly, I got to know that the new spring security oauth2 is changed, then I come to learn:https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.5.2/reference/html5/.
However, when I try to add the annotation `@EnableAuthorizationServer` to the "main method", the Intellij throws it's deprecated".

Then, I tried to check the version:  springframework.boot:2.5.2 ,  spring-security-oauth2:2.5.1.RELEASE, spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.5.2.

It means all the dependencies are new, and the doc is new too.

Then why the Intellij says the annotation is deprecated? I just wanna follow the new trend. Please tell me what to do?

thanks a lot.

Comment: By now, I got to know that the spring security oauth2 is in maintenance... So what shall I do to build an OAuth authorization server to provide the token to implement the "password flow"? The "migration guide" mainly tells about the "client", "login" and "resource server", so what to do about the "authorization server"?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation to which you have linked states, the project is in maintenance mode. Where possible, it should not be used and the equivalent features in Spring Security 5.x should be used instead.

The deprecation message on `EnableAuthorizationServer` links to a [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide). From there you can learn about the [Spring Authorization Server project](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server) which you may want to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it means the new version of spring security oauth2 is not recommended. Maybe later the project is available.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I got to know the migration is mainly about the "client", "resource" and "login", so what shall I do to implement an "authorization server"? Thanks for your kind.

Comment: @Noobman No, it doesn't mean *new version of spring security oauth2 is not recommended*. It means it is recommended to use the new version (Spring Security 5).

Comment: @Noobman Why do you asking: *so what shall I do to implement an "authorization server"?* Didn't you read the link [Spring Authorization Server project](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server)?

Comment: Oh, there is a project named "oauth2-authorization-server", and 2 sub-directory "config/annotation/web" and "oauth2".